# Android login google in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I make an app for android and i want to implement a leaderboard. My problem is that the user have to login first and THIS is my problem.

All the tutorials from the [Google Developer Website](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) or others weren't really helpful.

**My Problem:** My hole app acts in the MainActivity because I use OpenGL to show all the animations and 2D graphics. But in every tutorial i found they had an seperate class for singin in.

**My Question:** Could anyone help/tell me how I can implement the signin in the MainActivity on the easiest way.

I appreciate every (constructive) answere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to implement

```
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    View.OnClickListener
```

to your MainActivity. You don't need to create new activity.

The whole set up of logining in G+ account is there: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

And after succesfull logining into your app (you must create game services for your game in developer console first -> your logining email needs to be on the list of testers) you just create leaderboard in developer console.
To show the google leaderboard use this:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
    LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

And to submit the score use this:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, LEADERBOARD_ID, 1337);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented Google signin in different class so you can use it any activity or fragment. Check here http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/12/integrate-google-plus-in-android-app.html

Get the full code from github and check it.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
This is up-to-date integration library with easy to understand guides
More is here
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating